# Adding Objects to Array in a different class

Tags: android, arraylist

First of all Hello there, first time posting here.

I have 4 classes that are required to put Strings to an Array that is in a different class.

If the user selects and option in my switch statement I would like it to send the information to the array in Array Class. This works well the trouble i am having, once the user then goes to a different page and the code is executed it is wiping the array

```
public UserSelectionArray userArrayClass = new UserSelectionArray();
```

This is the code. and I also know that this is the problem as it is instantiating a new Array every time this code is executed.

How would I send the Strings to the array from individual classes without having to instantiate a new UserArrayClass.

I hope I've explained this correctly.

Regards

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    if (UserSelectionArray.getInstance().myArray.size() < 4) {
                        UserSelectionArray.getInstance().myArray.add("Guiness");
                        Log.d("Array contains", "" + UserSelectionArray.getInstance().myArray);

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(BeerChoice.this, "Maximum of 4 Drinks Reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // goto confirm page


                    }


                    break;
```

///// User Selection Class

```
public class UserSelectionArray {

ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();


private static UserSelectionArray instance;

public static UserSelectionArray getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new UserSelectionArray();

    }

    return new UserSelectionArray();
}

public UserSelectionArray() {


}
```

}

Comment: please show a piece of code. There are many ways to send and retrieve datas in different activities....

Comment: I dont understand totally, but you can use Object array. so that, you can keep every type object in this array

Comment: not clear what exactly u wants please be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the Singleton pattern for your userArrayClass. Do something like this:

```
public class userArrayClass {

    private static userArrayClass instance;

    public static userArrayClass getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new userArrayClass();
        }       
    }

    private userArrayClass(){
        //Constructor
    }


    .... /*Rest of the code */

}
```

And later access the userArrayClass object this way:

```
userArrayClass.getInstance().doSomething();
```

This way you will be able to access the same userArrayClass object from anywhere inside the program.

Comment: Ive tried doing this and the code looks error free, however i get a null pointer exception

Comment: On what? Did you init all the fields (the arrays, lists or whatever) in the constructor?

Comment: Updated main Question

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method in your UserArrayClass

```
setArray(String[] newArray) {
this.array = newArray;
}
```